# Where can I find regulations for establishing shooting (firearm) schools in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, regulations, firearms

Are there set laws or regulations that govern the setup of a clay pigeon school in the United Kingdom.
If so, where can I find the specifications.

Comment: "clay pigeon school"? As in the clay pigeons shot with shotguns?

Comment: Yes. Shooting schools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many regulations to consider, for the firearms themselves, the permits needed by potential customers, and licensing you will need as a business dealing with firearms and ammunition. Start with the Home Office: https://www.gov.uk/search?q=firearms

I.e., https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/479794/Guidance_on_Firearms_Licensing_Law_Nov_2015_v16.pdf